# Interval variable for instant values

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

can someone help to find an appropriate solution to be able to calculate the sum of values with the interval variable?

I have a metric  **`health_checker`** that reports only 2 values - **0** and **1**

Also here is my query

```
sum by(device,email)(last_over_time(health_checker{job="JobName"}[1d]))
```

Without pressing the **Instant**  button values are not summarised. Like on the screenshot below.

[image]

If **Instant** is enabled then values are summarised and instead of showing three rows with value **1**, it shows one correctly summarised row with value **3**, and all is OK except interval, I need to hardcode it, also when I’m using **$interval** variable instead of hardcoded interval I am unable to see any data.

My goal is to summarise values and be able to view them in time range using the **$interval** variable